# Compatibility ids between same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a compatibility table between ids using SQL 2014.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
[FromId] int,
[ToId] int,
)
```

Let's say I have Id 1 compatible with Id 2 so I'll insert FromId 1 => ToId 2, but also 2 => 1 which is actually the same valid record.
Now when I try to query this table, I need to be able to retrieve 2 when I ask for 1 and 1 when I ask for 2 even if the 2=> 1 relation is not inserted.

I did it in this way:

I insert in one way (for example 1 => 2) and I added a trigger to avoid inserting 2 => 1 because is the same as 1 => 2. Also I created a view that will return all possible combinations with an UNION like this:

```
SELECT FromId, ToId FROM MyTable 
UNION
SELECT ToId, FromId FROM MyTable
```

This works fine to me, I just need to know if I'm over complicating logic because there is something already done to handle this or a better way to do it.

Comment: Well, a union is pretty straight forward so you answered your own question--but you did complicate the question itself I admit. I'm not sure if `=>` is `less than or equal to` or a literal arrow like `-->` much less what the overall goal is.

Comment: sorry you are right I wanted to write this --> not this =>

Answer (score 1):

A `union` is rather expensive.  You can replace it with `union all` given the restrictions that your trigger enforces:

```
SELECT FromId, ToId
FROM MyTable 
UNION ALL
SELECT ToId, FromId
FROM MyTable ;
```

I want to add that you don't need a trigger to enforce that `FromId < ToId`.  You can do that with a `check` constraint.

If you want *either* relationship in the table, but not the inverse, then you can still avoid a trigger:

```
alter table mytable add minfromto as (case when fromid < toid then fromid else toid end);
alter table mytable add maxfromto as (case when fromid < toid then toid else fromid end);

create unique index unq_mytable_minfromto_maxfromto on mytable(minfromto, maxfromto);
```

Comment: Hi, if check constraint is better, I can do that, but I don't understand the way you are doing it

Comment: I don't get your alter table, is that ok?

Comment: @carlosm . . . The check constraint would enforce that `fromid` is always less than `toid`.  That means that some inserts would fail.  The unique key on the computed columns guarantees that the pair is unique, in either order.

Comment: I see your point, the thing is that your script is failing as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple CASE WHEN THEN ELSE (without trigger and view), and put your search condition in 'when' like this:

```
     SELECT CASE 
        WHEN FromId = 1 THEN ToId
        WHEN ToId = 1 THEN FromId
        ELSE NULL
        END AS RESULT
    FROM table
    WHERE
        FromId = 1 OR ToId = 1
```

Comment: the problem is that I want to avoid entering 1-->2 and 2-->1 relation, with one is enough

Comment: I understood it, suppose that your table contain only FromId = 1 | ToId = 2 and you search the relation of '1'. so, with my request you will get Result = 2.
And if your table contain only one row  FromId = 2 | ToId = 1 and you search the relation of '1', you will get also Result = 2

Comment: I Update my answer I forgot from table ! :D

Comment: I see your point by in that case I need to hard code the id I'm looking for, I want something like putting the id in the where condition will give me the result no matter if it's 1 or two